# Можно ли сделать так, чтобы цветной фон уходил под полупрозрачный так, чтобы его не перекрывал?

Tags: css, css3

Есть 2 блока с фоновыми картинками. Один фон цветной, второй - на прозрачном фоне с рваными краями.

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы цветной фон уходил под полупрозрачный так, чтобы его не перекрывал и при этом не был виден под полупрозрачностью?
Т.е. сделать в итоге так, чтобы создать эффект обрезанной рванкой цветного фона снизу

```css
#content-1 {
  background: url("https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/805160/7d7a9933-7054-4cd9-b6a9-4d6f59236334/orig") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  padding: 50px 50px 250px;
  margin-bottom: -200px;
}

#content-2 {
  background: url("https://b.radikal.ru/b36/1902/14/9f58bb2a658f.png") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  padding: 250px 50px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sit amet lectus placerat, hendrerit tellus at, semper nibh. Nulla lacus dui, tincidunt in enim sed, aliquet tincidunt enim. Phasellus lacinia turpis velit, non ullamcorper magna ultrices
  id. Fusce ac lectus lectus. In bibendum justo risus, eu mattis elit lacinia a. Vestibulum ullamcorper feugiat purus, vel rhoncus lacus. Vivamus eu fringilla dolor, eu consequat ipsum. Nam tempus orci nec felis feugiat mattis. Nulla metus dolor, suscipit
  ac turpis et, elementum rhoncus nunc. Donec placerat egestas dui, vitae pellentesque dui euismod sit amet. Nam mattis velit et sapien maximus ultrices. In vel sem felis. Nulla auctor vulputate neque eu egestas. Nunc nunc nisi, porttitor a vestibulum
  et, sodales eu nulla. Ut bibendum justo eu magna porttitor dictum. Quisque tortor diam, porta vel odio id, consequat mollis odio. Phasellus sit amet urna consequat, euismod orci in, laoreet purus. Praesent nisi orci, eleifend ac ultricies quis, porttitor
  vitae metus. Sed volutpat nunc augue, at viverra felis lobortis vitae. Sed vestibulum feugiat tortor, id iaculis ligula.
</div>
<div id="content-2">
  Phasellus blandit, magna consequat fermentum egestas, dolor lacus tincidunt nibh, sed elementum purus sapien ornare purus. Sed congue rhoncus magna, a ullamcorper velit dictum ut. Cras mollis, nibh sagittis viverra pharetra, velit odio mattis felis, sit
  amet luctus nulla arcu id odio. Duis augue arcu, tempor ut eleifend vel, suscipit at sapien. Sed venenatis elit sit amet massa vehicula condimentum. Nam eleifend, dolor vel lobortis imperdiet, odio neque lobortis nisl, vitae facilisis lectus ligula
  non sapien. Nulla vel orci semper, sodales est non, ultrices ligula. Suspendisse a volutpat turpis. Nam laoreet dui volutpat ullamcorper vestibulum. Etiam non fringilla ipsum. Suspendisse nec nulla magna. Curabitur faucibus dapibus urna ac tempor. Maecenas
  lobortis libero eu turpis imperdiet, in sagittis nisi auctor. Sed elit ex, ultricies ac nisl eget, consectetur mattis ipsum. Vivamus feugiat metus eget lacus ultrices, eu blandit metus gravida. Fusce vitae ligula a tellus porta placerat non pulvinar
  nulla. Proin fringilla libero eget nibh commodo, a consequat neque consectetur. Etiam tempus orci eu mollis congue. Fusce interdum scelerisque arcu, at scelerisque justo facilisis ut. Morbi sit amet ipsum ut mi vestibulum fringilla. In pretium a quam
  in consectetur.
</div>
```

Comment: У Вас вторая картинка JPG же, у неё нет прозрачности.

Comment: @Kvilios справедливо, заменил на `png`, суть осталась прежней

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы имеете ввиду такой эффект?

```css
#content-1 {
  background: url("https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/805160/7d7a9933-7054-4cd9-b6a9-4d6f59236334/orig") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  padding: 50px 50px 250px;
  margin-bottom: -300px;
}

#content-2 {
  background: url("https://b.radikal.ru/b36/1902/14/9f58bb2a658f.png") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  padding: 300px 50px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sit amet lectus placerat, hendrerit tellus at, semper nibh. Nulla lacus dui, tincidunt in enim sed, aliquet tincidunt enim. Phasellus lacinia turpis velit, non ullamcorper magna ultrices
  id. Fusce ac lectus lectus. In bibendum justo risus, eu mattis elit lacinia a. Vestibulum ullamcorper feugiat purus, vel rhoncus lacus. Vivamus eu fringilla dolor, eu consequat ipsum. Nam tempus orci nec felis feugiat mattis. Nulla metus dolor, suscipit
  ac turpis et, elementum rhoncus nunc. Donec placerat egestas dui, vitae pellentesque dui euismod sit amet. Nam mattis velit et sapien maximus ultrices. In vel sem felis. Nulla auctor vulputate neque eu egestas. Nunc nunc nisi, porttitor a vestibulum
  et, sodales eu nulla. Ut bibendum justo eu magna porttitor dictum. Quisque tortor diam, porta vel odio id, consequat mollis odio. Phasellus sit amet urna consequat, euismod orci in, laoreet purus. Praesent nisi orci, eleifend ac ultricies quis, porttitor
  vitae metus. Sed volutpat nunc augue, at viverra felis lobortis vitae. Sed vestibulum feugiat tortor, id iaculis ligula.
</div>
<div id="content-2">
  Phasellus blandit, magna consequat fermentum egestas, dolor lacus tincidunt nibh, sed elementum purus sapien ornare purus. Sed congue rhoncus magna, a ullamcorper velit dictum ut. Cras mollis, nibh sagittis viverra pharetra, velit odio mattis felis, sit
  amet luctus nulla arcu id odio. Duis augue arcu, tempor ut eleifend vel, suscipit at sapien. Sed venenatis elit sit amet massa vehicula condimentum. Nam eleifend, dolor vel lobortis imperdiet, odio neque lobortis nisl, vitae facilisis lectus ligula
  non sapien. Nulla vel orci semper, sodales est non, ultrices ligula. Suspendisse a volutpat turpis. Nam laoreet dui volutpat ullamcorper vestibulum. Etiam non fringilla ipsum. Suspendisse nec nulla magna. Curabitur faucibus dapibus urna ac tempor. Maecenas
  lobortis libero eu turpis imperdiet, in sagittis nisi auctor. Sed elit ex, ultricies ac nisl eget, consectetur mattis ipsum. Vivamus feugiat metus eget lacus ultrices, eu blandit metus gravida. Fusce vitae ligula a tellus porta placerat non pulvinar
  nulla. Proin fringilla libero eget nibh commodo, a consequat neque consectetur. Etiam tempus orci eu mollis congue. Fusce interdum scelerisque arcu, at scelerisque justo facilisis ut. Morbi sit amet ipsum ut mi vestibulum fringilla. In pretium a quam
  in consectetur.
</div>
```

Comment: т.к. мой вопрос был не до конца описан, то засчитаю как верный, но просто попробуйте сделать аналогичное с полупрозрачной картинкой
https://jsfiddle.net/38yd7wzp/

Comment: @Вася Можете попробовать использовать маски (но, к сожалению, они далеко не всеми браузерами пока поддерживаются): https://jsfiddle.net/k6fuxg7L/ Только изображение предварительно надо перевернуть, т.к. маскируемая сторона - непрозрачная. P.S. Добавлю, что если изображение полупрозрачное, то и маска "полуприменится", т.е. она наложится, но изображение тем будет бледнее, чем прозрачнее маска.

Answer (score 1):

У блока можно указывать множество картинок через запятую:

```
background: url("https://b.radikal.ru/b36/1902/14/9f58bb2a658f.png") repeat-x 
left 200px, url("https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/805160/7d7a9933-7054- 
4cd9-b6a9-4d6f59236334/orig") no-repeat center center;
```

```css
#content-1 {
  background: url("https://b.radikal.ru/b36/1902/14/9f58bb2a658f.png") repeat-x left 250px, url("https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/805160/7d7a9933-7054-4cd9-b6a9-4d6f59236334/orig") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  padding: 50px 50px 250px;
  margin-bottom: -200px;
}

#content-2 {
  background-color: #FF8040;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  padding: 50px 50px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sit amet lectus placerat, hendrerit tellus at, semper nibh. Nulla lacus dui, tincidunt in enim sed, aliquet tincidunt enim. Phasellus lacinia turpis velit, non ullamcorper magna ultrices
  id. Fusce ac lectus lectus. In bibendum justo risus, eu mattis elit lacinia a. Vestibulum ullamcorper feugiat purus, vel rhoncus lacus. Vivamus eu fringilla dolor, eu consequat ipsum. Nam tempus orci nec felis feugiat mattis. Nulla metus dolor, suscipit
  ac turpis et, elementum rhoncus nunc. Donec placerat egestas dui, vitae pellentesque dui euismod sit amet. Nam mattis velit et sapien maximus ultrices. In vel sem felis. Nulla auctor vulputate neque eu egestas. Nunc nunc nisi, porttitor a vestibulum
  et, sodales eu nulla. Ut bibendum justo eu magna porttitor dictum. Quisque tortor diam, porta vel odio id, consequat mollis odio. Phasellus sit amet urna consequat, euismod orci in, laoreet purus. Praesent nisi orci, eleifend ac ultricies quis, porttitor
  vitae metus. Sed volutpat nunc augue, at viverra felis lobortis vitae. Sed vestibulum feugiat tortor, id iaculis ligula.
</div>
<div id="content-2">
  Phasellus blandit, magna consequat fermentum egestas, dolor lacus tincidunt nibh, sed elementum purus sapien ornare purus. Sed congue rhoncus magna, a ullamcorper velit dictum ut. Cras mollis, nibh sagittis viverra pharetra, velit odio mattis felis, sit
  amet luctus nulla arcu id odio. Duis augue arcu, tempor ut eleifend vel, suscipit at sapien. Sed venenatis elit sit amet massa vehicula condimentum. Nam eleifend, dolor vel lobortis imperdiet, odio neque lobortis nisl, vitae facilisis lectus ligula
  non sapien. Nulla vel orci semper, sodales est non, ultrices ligula. Suspendisse a volutpat turpis. Nam laoreet dui volutpat ullamcorper vestibulum. Etiam non fringilla ipsum. Suspendisse nec nulla magna. Curabitur faucibus dapibus urna ac tempor. Maecenas
  lobortis libero eu turpis imperdiet, in sagittis nisi auctor. Sed elit ex, ultricies ac nisl eget, consectetur mattis ipsum. Vivamus feugiat metus eget lacus ultrices, eu blandit metus gravida. Fusce vitae ligula a tellus porta placerat non pulvinar
  nulla. Proin fringilla libero eget nibh commodo, a consequat neque consectetur. Etiam tempus orci eu mollis congue. Fusce interdum scelerisque arcu, at scelerisque justo facilisis ut. Morbi sit amet ipsum ut mi vestibulum fringilla. In pretium a quam
  in consectetur.
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, но в данном случае вы и сами видите, как это топорно выглядит

Comment: Как "Топорно"??

Comment: ну сами взгляните
https://c.radikal.ru/c25/1902/83/a71052636140.png

Comment: Тогда обрежте картинку снизу и вместо `200px` поставте `bottom`

Comment: не понимаю, что это может дать. решения не вижу, особенно, если рванный фон полупрозрачный

Comment: Вы пробовали хотя-бы?

Comment: я-то пробовал, а вы попробуйте сделать то, что предлагаете с полупрозрачной картинкой здесь и чтобы это не выглядело топорно
https://jsfiddle.net/38yd7wzp/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c0vkw9o5/1/

Comment: вы переходили по ссылке, что я выше скинул? jsfiddle.net/38yd7wzp

Comment: да, но я не понял как вы хотите что бы выглядело нормально с полупрозачной?

Comment: примерно так, где нижний это полупрозрачный фон
https://d.radikal.ru/d06/1902/c1/2ad41b565a70.png
ставлю лайк за стремление помочь

Comment: Ну, и в чем конкретно проблема? возмите мой код jsfiddle.net/c0vkw9o5/1 и поменяйте картинку на свою

Comment: поменял http://jsfiddle.net/wkazftv9/
ну а сейчас проблему видите? цветная картинка должна полностью уходить под полупрозрачную, чтобы последняя была видна с четкими границами, а не как сейчас - проглядывать сквозь нее